# Combining Vue v-for with GSAP transitions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, transition, gsap, v-for

I have two components, one that generates a bunch of divs

```
<div
      v-for="(app, index) in items.apps"
      ref="appIcon"
      :key="index"
    >
        <div @click="openApp(app)"></div>
</div>
```

with a method that pushes the clicked div into an array of `openedApps`

```
openApp(appName) {
      this.items.openedApps.push(appName)
}
```

then, in a separate component, the array of `apps` is generated dynamically based on it's content

```
<div
      v-for="(app, index) in items.openedApps"
      ref="appWindow"
      :key="index"
    >
</div>
```

and I want to make transitions for all items in `openedApps` array, but separately, preferably using GSAP.

but when I do it like this

```
mounted() {
    let { appWindow } = this.$refs
    let timeline = new TimelineLite()

    timeline.from(appWindow, 1, {opacity:0})
  }
```

nothing happens and I get an error from GSAP saying "GSAP target undefined not found".

So I'm guessing there's something wrong with the usage of mounted() hook here, but I have no clue what to do. Been hitting my head against the wall on this one for two days trying to figure it out because I really want to use GSAP for this project instead of just the standard , but I just dont know how to succesfully target certain divs using GSAP and Vue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about Vue to answer this question right now. It'd be helpful if you made a minimal demo using something like CodePen or CodeSandbox though. Side note: We highly recommend using [GSAP 3 formatting](https://greensock.com/3-migration/), I'm not sure where you're learning this old formatting from.

Comment: Weirdly enough, just using the new formatting seemed to fix the problem. I can now use <transition-group> in combination with JS hooks enter, before-enter and leave. So thanks for the help I guess :D